# How can I get OmniFaces extensionless URLs and ICEfaces ace:menuItem component to work together?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, icefaces, omnifaces

I'm using extensionless URLs from OmniFaces (2.1) with ICEfaces (3.3) so that my URL's don't require the *.jsf* suffix.  The problem is that one of the ICEfaces components doesn't like this:

```
<ace:menuBar>
    <ace:submenu label="assets menu">
        <ace:menuItem value="assets" url="assets"/>
```

The page loads fine and the links work fine, but the following message is flooding my logs:

*JSF1091: No mime type could be found for file assets.  To resolve this, add a mime-type mapping to the applications web.xml.*

It appears that JSF doesn't like that my URL doesn't have an extension.  I can't seem to find any  setting in web.xml to resolve this.

Comment: Which server are you deploying to? Try putting `<mime-mapping><extension>xhtml</extension><mime-type>text/html</mime-type></mime-mapping>` in bottom of `web.xml`.

Comment: I'm using Glassfish 4.1.  Unfortunately, the mime-mapping did not work.

Comment: Looks like an issue with ICEfaces 3.3.  This problem isn't happening in 4.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is ICEfaces 3.3.  I tried this under ICEfaces 4.0 and there are no entries in the logs.